# Reading integer number from database returns floating point

Tags: oracle, delphi, floating-point

We've got a table in an Oracle DB defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE AVALUES
(
  ACODE   VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
  ATYPE   NUMBER NOT NULL,
  ANAME   VARCHAR2(50),
  CREATED DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
)
```

Within Delphi we have a query in an ADOQuery component akin to this which returns the value to our application:

```
with qryComp do
begin
  Close;
  SQL.Text := 
    'SELECT ATYPE FROM AVALUES ORDER BY CREATED';
  Open;
  while not EOF do
  begin
    AddComponents('NAME' + FieldByName('ATYPE').AsString);
    Next;
  end;
  Close;
end;
```

Deployed on many various client PCs this has worked fine for years, and nothing in our code has changed. On a few client PCs however it's recently started returning, say, *1.999999999969* instead of *2*, which causes the application to crash. We've tried looking for the problem but it's very intermittent - connected via remote desktop to the client computer, we can't replicate it at all.

Any suggestions for things I can do to investigate this further? As it's intermittent and only happens on a few computers it's difficult to debug. I think it might be a problem with the Oracle client, but I'm not sure how we can actually verify that.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Integers are exactly representable in IEEE754 floating point. There would have to be calculations performed for a value like this to be returned. Seems pretty odd. How are you putting the values into the database? Are you performing floating point calculations at all? If you think this is an integer why are you storing as floating point? If it really is an integer then the solution is to store as an integer.

Comment: Does ATYPE really needs Oracle NUMBER full floating point precision? Or could you declare it something alike NUMBER(6)? NUMBER handles different situations depending on how you declare it. Using the proper declaration will also save space for the column size, which is given by the formula ROUND((length(p)+s)/2))+1 where p is the precision and s is 0 or 1 depending on the number sign. If you just use NUMBER, p = 38. Also NUMBER doesn't store data in IEEE754 format. BINARY_FLOAT and BINARY_DOUBLE do. See "Oracle Database SQL Reference" for details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only thing I can see possible is differences between the FPU control word on client machines causing the precision to be handled differently, because of inherent rounding issues with dealing with floating point types. (See [Set8087CW](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Set8087CW) in the Delphi docs; the link is for XE2's documentation, but there's  no significant change recently that I'm aware of, so they should work.)

There are four ways to fix it (one not probable, three fairly easy):

- Change the database column to actually be an `integer` type instead of a `NUMBER`
- Directly ask for an `integer` value, and convert it yourself

  `AddComponent('Name' + IntToStr(FieldByName('ATYPE').AsInteger));`
- Change the code that uses the column, either at the point of use:

  `AddComponents(Format('NAME%d', [FieldByName('ATYPE').AsInteger]));`

or in `AddComponents` itself:

```
procedure AddComponents(Prefix: string; Value: Integer);
begin
  DoWhateverIDo(Prefix + IntToStr(Value));
end;

// calling code
AddComponents('Name', FieldByName('ATYPE').AsInteger);
```

- Explicitly set the value of the 8087CW before working with the database, and set it back when you're finished. This seems to be the worst option to me; there's an example of doing this at the documentation link I posted above.

Comment: Hi Ken! Thanks for the pointer towards Set8087CW - it turns out the problem is that a 3rd party DLL is fiddling with this value under certain circumstances and now we know that, we can stop it. :)

Comment: If the problem is with the control word then you must be doing floating point calcs. But if that is so, and you app is sensitive to the difference between 2 and 1.999999999 then you have a problem. If the sensitivity leads to a crash then I really think you are doing something badly wrong. Just running on different hardware could lead to similar differences and maintaining control of the FP control word is difficult. If this really is an integer then you must deal with the problem at source and not try to paper over the cracks.

Comment: @David, there are known issues with Delphi and some DLLs that change the FP control word, resulting in exceptions in Delphi after the DLL's functionality is used. Try searching [CodeNewsFast](http://codenewsfast.com/) with 'Set8087CW`, and you'll find 500+ related articles. IIRC, there are a couple of specific products, possibly from MS, like [IE9](http://codenewsfast.com/cnf/thread/649961/waThreadBookmark.1751090) that cause problems with Delphi when they're used, but I'll leave identifying them from the articles as an exercise for you. :)

Comment: @Ken as the author of an finite element structural analysis software, I happen to know more than I care to about the troubles of floating point control words. I wouldn't say the issues are with Delphi per se, more that the whole system is anarchy. My point in this question is that if code doing integer calcs is sensitive to the fp control word then it is fatally flawed. I understand perfectly how such sensitivity can arise. But if it does, then OP really should stop using FP as if it were exact. It is not.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem with the data type **Currency** (Blog article: ["**Why 1.99 suddenly no longer equals 1.99**"](http://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2009/05/04/why-is-199-199/)). It looks like some DLLs modify a FPU (processor) control word. This explains why the problem is machine-dependent.
I also found that Delphi contains a `SafeLoadLibrary` function, which restores the control word. But it is not a big help, because after loading the DLL, still any call of a DLL function could mess up the control word again.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle NUMBER data type is floating point data type, so you have problem of float / double approximation. Be sure to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: I'm aware it's a float data type. It just seems strange that in 99 cases out of 100 it returns the value we wanted stored, and in that 1 odd case it doesn't, but not all the time. I assumed it would be consistent if it was related to approximation.

Comment: Do you set FPU control word ? (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Set8087CW)

Comment: It should be consistent. Control word should not have any effect on reading an exactly representable value like this.

Comment: While Oracle's NUMBER type is a floating point type, it is a base-100 floating point numbering system as documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci03typ.htm#autoId11) and thus does not suffer from many of the nasty problems found in base-2^n floating point numbers. As others have pointed out this error has something to do with the translation from NUMBER to the PC's base-2^n (i.e. IEEE) floating point format, and later manipulation of those values. Unfortunately Delphi chooses to convert NUMBER to Double or some other floating point type. Bad-bad-BAD!

Comment: @Bob "does not suffer from many of the nasty problems found in base-2^n floating point" is a skewed view of the world. `NUMBER` is right for some problems, binary floating point is right for other problems. You wouldn't suggest that `NUMBER` would be appropriate for scientific or engineering calculations would you? And I wouldn't suggest IEEE-754 is appropriate for currency calculations.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I've said it before and I'll say it again - base-2^n floating point proves the existence of God by negation, as it is clearly the work of the devil. :-)  More to the point - in many (dare I say most?) contexts, base-2^n floating point is the WRONG solution - and yet, due to many reasons, it's often the one chosen.  In a base 10 world the places where a non-base-10 numbering system is OK are limited.  YMMV

Comment: @Bob In most scientific and engineering applications, the base of the number system used for calculations is irrelevant. In so many of those applications it is not a base 10 world.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I agree that in sci/eng apps where minor rounding errors are acceptable the base does not matter as much.  In a business environment, where many of us spend most of our programming time doing "money and widget-counting" stuff, the base is critical to providing expected results.  I suspect this is why Oracle chose a software-implemented base-100 floating point format for NUMBER (which is IMO one of the best features in Oracle) rather than a more performant but less predictable base-2^n format.  As always, YMMV.

Comment: @Bob Yeah, you don't seem to get it. In your world, decimal base is critical. In my world, there are rounding errors no matter what base you use. That's because scientific and engineering calcs model the continuous number system with a discrete data type. So no matter what base you use, there are errors. Try representing pi in a decimal floating point value exactly. No can do.